# 'modules appear to be missing' - py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I am using py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe and converted a .py file to .exe. The problem is that it won't open as it says something like 'unable to import Frame' when I try to open the .exe file. 'Frame' is another .py file which I wrote some code in.

Also, when I open another .exe(converted from .py) file which does not import some .py file which I made, then it opens without any problem.

Here is my setup.py file.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob
import sys
import os
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Microsoft.VC90.CRT")
print os.path.isdir("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Microsoft.VC90.CRT")
data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT",glob(r'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\*.*'))]

setup(data_files="",console=["C:\\3d-Model\\bin\\Application.py"])
```

**EDIT**: 
I understood the problem. the modules present only in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ gets imported by the .exe file. 
The question now is do I have to copy every module the .exe file is trying to import to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ before running py2exe or is there any other easier way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add an empty __init__.py inside your python/sitepakages/module which it says import error

Comment: by the way which module does it shows import error

Comment: Thanks. It somehow helped me figure out what caused the problem. Please see the **EDIT** .

Comment: yes! u need to place '__init__.py' to every module your using in your project. since __init__.py tell to your py2exe convertor that there is a python module here

Comment: You mean I need to place a totally empty "init.py" in every folder(and subfolder as well?) where there is .py file that my .exe needs to import.

Comment: yes! you need to place

Comment: [g.d.d.c](http://stackoverflow.com/users/351031/g-d-d-c) I am not sure but I think are you confusing "Frame" with wx.Frame. Frame here is a .py file.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is I updated the `'setup.py'` file to contain the paths to the missing modules, using

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <path_to_missing_modules>)
```

This way I do no need to polute the `...\site_packages\` folder.

Comment: I  know I'm quite late but I'm having the same issues. Could you elaborate more on how you solved it? I also started a question but no answers so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261495/py2exe-the-following-modules-appear-to-be-missing

Comment: Not sure about your link below.

Answer (score 0):

you need to place `'__init__.py'` to every module your using in your project. since init.py tell to your py2exe convertor that there is a python module here.

Since i have faced the same issue Few days back. with `zope.interface and mp_tools` i placed empty `__init__.py` worked fine for me

Comment: please Correct me if i am wrong! dont simply downvote

Comment: See my comment to the OP on the _question_.  The presence or absence of `__init__.py` files won't affect whether or not py2exe includes the wx libraries if they're imported in even a single top level module.

Comment: Simply placing an empty __init__.py file did not help. I manually copied the whole folder containing the Frame.py file to the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ before runnning py2exe and it WORKED!!! :) .... People should read the question properly before downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked for me.
Manually copying the folder containing the files which your .py(to be converted to .exe) file imports, before running py2exe, to Python27\Lib\site-packages\ fixes such problems I guess.