# py2exe the following modules appear to be missing

Tags: python, exe, executable, py2exe

As the title says, when I'm trying to use py2exe to create a Windows executable file, I get this error:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'ElementC14N', 'OpenSSL.SSL', '_frozen_importlib', '_imp', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'backports.ssl_match_hostname', 'builtins', 'certifi', 'charade.universaldetector', 'configparser', 'datrie', 'genshi.core', 'html', 'html.entities', 'html.parser', 'http', 'http.client', 'http.cookies', 'http.server', 'importlib.machinery', 'importlib.util', 'ipaddr', 'ipaddress', 'java', 'lzma', 'ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification', 'ndg.httpsclient.subj_alt_name', 'netbios', 'ordereddict', 'org.python.modules.posix.PosixModule', 'packages.six.moves', 'packages.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError', 'packages.ssl_match_hostname.match_hostname', 'packages.urllib3.util.Timeout', 'packages.urllib3.util.parse_url', 'packaging.specifiers', 'packaging.version', 'parsers.process', 'pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib', 'pyasn1.codec.der', 'pyasn1.type', 'queue', 'redis', 'reprlib', 'serializer.serialize', 'setuptools_svn', 'simplejson', 'sitecustomize', 'treebuilders.getTreeBuilder', 'treewalkers.getTreeWalker', 'trie.Trie', 'urllib.error', 'urllib.parse', 'urllib.request', 'urllib3', 'usercustomize', 'win32com.client.gencache', 'win32evtlog', 'win32evtlogutil', 'win32pipe', 'win32wnet', 'wincertstore', 'winreg', 'xmlrpc.client']

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   OLEAUT32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
   IMM32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ole32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
   COMDLG32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMDLG32.dll
   COMCTL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
   GDI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
```

I've read some stuff about it here on stackoverflow but I couldn't find a clear answer in which I could find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Missing modules are usually just warnings. If there's strong dependency, you can put it in options for py2exe as 'includes'. As for the dlls mentioned, you can avoid it by putting it in list in dll_excludes. (Again in options for py2exe)